# How can disable th:href link for a defined th:value

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm a new in Java Spring Development.
There is a Thymeleaf code for generating active "href-links":

```
<td> <a id="requeststatus"
        th:each="requeststatus : ${requeststatuses}" 
        th:if="(${requeststatus.id} == ${request.request_status_id})" 
          th:href="@{'/system/request/edit/requeststatusid/' + ${request.id}}" 
             th:text="${requeststatus.title}" th:value="${requeststatus.id}"
        th:unless="${requeststatus.id} >= 4" >                              
     </a>
 </td>
```

For th:unless="${requeststatus.id} >= 4" i get empty ${requeststatus.title}, but i need get just not clickable requeststatus.title instead href for ${requeststatus.id} >= 4.

For example, how do I make a link inactive for ${requeststatus.id} >= 4 ?

Comment: You may get more flexibility by using a Thymeleaf [switch statement](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#switch-statements) instead of `if` and `unless`.

Comment: (On a separate note, I am not sure having a `<a>` link which is disabled/unclickable is a good idea. That's really just text, not a link - and therefore why display such text at all?)

Comment: Without <a> i got just source code instead href link in browser:

Comment: I am not saying "remove `<a>`". I am saying creating a disabled link is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments by @andrewJames conditionally disabling the link is not good practice. using `th:switch` you can replace the `a` with, for example a `span` with the same text.
In general if you want different behaviour depending on a variable it's best to wrap said behaviour in a `th:block` with an appropriate `if` or `switch case` condition

```html
<td> 
    <th:block th:each="requeststatus : ${requeststatuses}">
        <th:block th:switch="true">
            <a th:case="${requeststatus.id} < 4"
                id="requeststatus"
                th:href="@{'/system/request/edit/requeststatusid/' + ${request.id}}" 
                th:text="${requeststatus.title}" th:value="${requeststatus.id}" >                             
            </a>
            <span th:case="*" th:text="${requeststatus.title}"></span>
        </th:block>
    </th:block> 
 </td>
```

PS: in html the `id` should be unique, as such using a static id in a for loop should not be done, you could for example add the iter part to for loop and make ids like `requeststatus1` ,`..2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of CSS you can disable the hyperlink. Try the below

```html
a.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
<a href="link.html" class="disabled">Link</a>
```

Or with the JS

```html
<a href="javascript:function() { return false; }">link</a>
<a href="/" onclick="return false;">link</a>

/* You can also try void(0)

<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="cursor: default;">123n</a>
```

Hope this helps :)